# Verifying That The Coordinate I Click Is Within The GeoJsonLayer, Google Maps Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, geojson

I need to make sure that the point I click on the map is within the area of GeoJsonLayer I loaded into the map. GeoJsonLayer does't give LatLng of the point I clicked there, so it seems I have to get it from the map.

However, I can only choose setOnFeatureClickListener of GeoJsonLayer Feature or setOnMapClickListener of GoogleMaps to work. Not both of them at the same time. So I have to disable one to make the other work.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can try to make the layer as a list and use it in the `containsLocation()` method in the utility library? https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils/3.4.0/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation(double,double,java.util.List,boolean)

Comment: @Yrll, I have tried that but it doesn't give me accurate result. When I tried to convert the layer into polyline, the line was all over the place, maybe that's why